# Need help regarding scatter chart in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a scatter chart, I want to filter the table visually on the next page when any point is selected in the scatter chart, not by drill-through option.
Just click any point in the scatter chart and when I go table visual page, I need only the point details selected in the scatter chart.

Drill-through is not an exact solution.

Comment: Not possible, sorry.

Comment: You can emulate this by combining the pages and using bookmarks. Pain in the ass to maintain.

Comment: What if you use a custom tooltip to the scatter chart and add a table visual to that? The value from the scatter chart will be passed to it.